# Multisite Login problem

Tags: multisite, login

Ever since I upgraded my multisite network from 3.8 to 3.9, I have not been able to login through the main blog. It's a subdirectory install, not subdomain.

When I try to login to the main site: http://uspress.avenues.org/wp-login.php, get the the message "This user has elected to delete their account and the content is no longer available." This is not true. As far as I can see, you can't delete the main site, and I've checked the database and the site is set to be public.

I can log in if I go to a subsite's login page like so: http://uspress.avenues.org/kgarnier/wp-login.php

The home page of the main site is accessible, but if I try to go to another page on it, and I'm not logged in, I get the same error message. If I am logged in, I get the standard Wordpress 404 error page, but, bizarrely, it switches to another subsite that has been deleted (it had same behavior before it was deleted, I deleted when trying to fix this).

My wp-config file looks like this:

```
/* Multisite */
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'uspress.avenues.org');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('WP_DEFAULT_THEME', 'uspress');
```

I also added this cookie clearing code that was suggested on another site:

```
define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '');
define('COOKIEPATH', '');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '');
```

My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

One other weird but maybe unrelated thing: In the blog_versions table in the database, the main site has db_version 26692 and all the others have 27916.

Answer (score 2):

This is the relevant code from `ms_site_check()`:

```
$blog = get_blog_details();

// truncated

if ( '1' == $blog->deleted ) {
    if ( file_exists( WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/blog-deleted.php' ) )
        return WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/blog-deleted.php';
    else
        wp_die( __( 'This user has elected to delete their account and the content is no longer available.' ), '', array( 'response' => 410 ) );
}
```

So while site might not be *actually* deleted, for some reason WordPress is pretty confident that it is. The first thing I'd look at are DB queries being generated/run and data which is returned.

Comment: Aha. It seems I have a number of "deleted" sites with the path uspress.avenues.org/. I think this happened with a bad batch create of users and sites that I did a while ago. the ms_site_check() function is detecting one of those (blog_id 173) instead of the original main site (blog_id 1). I'm hoping I can just delete these sites from the wp_blogs table to fix this?

Comment: @Katy hard to say if that will fix it without hands–on debug through everything :) It might...

Comment: It actually did! I should probably clean out all the tables related to those sites, but it's working now so I'm afraid to do anything else.